# Apache Isis: How should I mark a table so that all entries are not openable

Tags: isis

I have a complex entity which is displayed in tables in different places. In one place I want to show a subset of properties only. For this projection I made a special in-memory object, which wraps the complex entity and has getters for the subset of properties only. How can I mark this inmemory object to be not openable?

Comment: Interesting name they chose.

Comment: You might want to ask this on the mailing list; I only noticed it here by chance.

Could you also clarify what you mean by "openable"; I'm guessing you want to disable the hyperlink on the icon?

Comment: correct, i want suppress/disable the link in the first column. I'll ask the question on the mailing list :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per [the Apache Isis mailing list](http://markmail.org/message/sbt4x7jmjjv744fq), can use the #cssClass() UI hint coupled with some custom CSS and Javascript.

Comment: Dans anwser from the mailing list inline: For example, the todo app uses #cssClass() so that completed todo items are
shown in a table with a strikethrough.  This comes from the "done" CSS
class: 

    public String cssClass() { return !isComplete() ? "todo" : "done"; }`


In webapp/css/application.css, if we add:
    
    tr.done a { pointer-events: none; cursor: default; }

and in webapp/scripts/application.js, if we add:

    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('tr.done a').click(function() { return false; });
    });

then the icon for each completed item cannot be clicked.